# Removing pages from build and nav?

Tags: jekyll

I need to be able to exclude certain files from the build. I am aware I can do this in the config file.

I also need a way to turn off a section of the website in the nav.

So I thought about having a flag in a data file, if it's false do not include a link to the section in the nav.

But how can I also use the same flag to prevent the section from being built?

Or is it easier to specify in config and check this flag in the nav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude files from builds, add this line to your `_config.yml`:

```
keep_files: [folder, "file.ext"]
```

The `folder` and the `file.ext` will be left untouched by Jekyll and will be included on builds.

OR

```
exclude: ["file.md", "otherfile.html"]
```

Both files won't be included on you site built by Jekyll at all.

---

Here:

> I also need a way to turn off a section of the website in the nav.

I'm not sure what you meant, but I guess you can probably do that with `if` statements:

In a post or a page front matter, add a variable indicating the section to exclude:

```
---
# your front matter settings
foo: bar # variable and value
---
```

Then, to your template, add:

```
{% if page.foo %}
  <div>this will display</div>
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if page.foo %}
  <div>this will display</div>
{% else %}
  <p>this will display when the above doesn't</p>
{% endif %}
```

Hope to have helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a config problem to me. I would put it in the config and have your includes and nav check the config values.